# How to enforce SSL in keycloak with Azure PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, azure, ssl, docker, keycloak

I am trying to configure keycloak to run with PostgreSQL (using Azure Database for PostgreSQL) using a docker container. I was able to do this as instructed in the keycloak documentation [here](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/server_installation/topics/database/datasource.html).

The problem that I am facing is, Azure Database for PostgreSQL has this option "Enforce SSL connection" set to "Enable" by default and the keycloak server is not working with that. It throws following error at the server startup.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.
```

If the option "Enforce SSL connection" is disabled it worked fine.

I would like to know how to specify this option to work with keycloak.

I am using a custom Dockerfile to download and boot keycloak server and passing the data-source parameters as environmental variables with the `docker run` command. I have tried [this approach](https://github.com/mnasyrov/keycloak-postgres-ssl) which worked fine when I point it to my PostgreSQL data-source without any modifications. But when I change it to be compatible with my own Dockerfile it gives the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here's what I did.

I overlooked the latest Dockerfile shared by jboss (which is available [here](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak)) and adopted the lines that I needed with the version of my requirement. Earlier I was trying to add postgreSQL configuration by my own as keycloak document was suggesting. Since it is now supported out of the box I changed my Dockerfile to be compatible with jboss Dockerfile for keycloak.

Also I introduced new env. variable to enforce SSL connection by stating `ssl=true` as guided [here](https://github.com/mnasyrov/keycloak-postgres-ssl)

Answer (score 0):

```
FATAL: SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.
```

I've seen this happen when the client IP address isn't included in the firewall rules on the PostgreSQL server. Try confirming the firewall is open for your IP in the Connection Security page in the portal or in the Azure CLI using `az postgres server firewall-rule list --resource-group --server-name`